# Wrong page number in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I have a document of 72 pages and page numbers in the table of contents are completely wrong. I'm trying to review everything step by step, so the first problem I've noticed is the following: I compile only the first part of the document:

```
% Style
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[header]{appendix}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Figures
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
My title page
\vfill
\end{titlepage}

\section*{Preface}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft}
\rule{5cm}{2cm}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{2mm} 
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}
\rule{5cm}{2cm}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{3cm}
\end{figure}

\chapter*{Abstract}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\lipsum[1-3]

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

And what I get is

> Contents:
>
> 1 Introduction p.5

while it should be

> Contents
>
> 1 Introduction p.4

but when I comment the first two images, I get the right page number.

Does anybody know why this happens? I've compiled 3 times but I still have the same problem.

I've also tried substituting the minipages by

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{logo1.jpg}
\end{subfigure} \quad
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{logo2.jpg}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

but I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: In the TOC I get pages 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 as I would expect given the setup. And you do not get 6,8,20 with the setup you provided. Please be a bit more specific about what your problem is?

Comment: You will need _at least_ 3 runs, did you try 4?

Comment: @daleif I've changed a bit the question, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @egreg Thanks a lot for the edits! I was going to do them myself :)

Comment: IT should be one single dotument for us to copy'n'paste that show the problem, pieces does  not help us much, plus people are less inclined to help.

Comment: @daleif I agree with you but I wouldn't know how to change it.. One just has to copy-paste the header plus the first code..

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried compiling more than 3 times but page numbers didn't change

Comment: please try to replace your `\includegraphics` by `\rule{1cm}[2cm}` (for some lengths that make sense) and produce an example that other people without the images can run to check the table of contents., then edit your question so in a single block it has everything from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` for people to use

Comment: @sandy.ale91 I get only three pages (but I don't know how big are your pictures). Note that you don't need neither `minipage` nor `figure` with `[H]` to typeset graphic objects that have no caption.

Comment: @egreg Really? How can I put two figures side by side then?

Comment: @sandy.ale91: you can just use the usual `\includegraphics`; the picture then does not float in the document. BTW: welcome to TeX.SX :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's wrong with `minipage` but finally I could solve the problem by always using `subfigure` and removing all the `[H]` from the figures and tables.